# Translate complex timestamp filter from SQL to HQL

Tags: sql, hql

I have to translate

```
AND <timestamp> BETWEEN (now()::date - interval '1 day' * (EXTRACT(DOW FROM now()::date) - 1) - interval '{{number_of_periods}} {{time_interval}}') AND (now()::date - interval '1 day' * (EXTRACT(DOW FROM now()::date) - 1))
```

from SQL to HQL - how can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: A logical description of this `WHERE` clause would be nice, along with your table schema.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
AND CAST(<timestamp> AS TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN CAST(now() AS DATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY * (EXTRACT(DOW FROM CAST(now() AS DATE)) - 1) - INTERVAL '{{number_of_periods}}' DAY * 7 AND (now() - INTERVAL '1' DAY * (EXTRACT(DOW FROM CAST(now() AS DATE)) - 1))
```